# Comparing subsequent rows and finding overlapping time intervals?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset, let's call it "Times":

```
> Times <- read.csv("Times.csv, header=TRUE)
> Times
Num     Start          End
1       00:09:41       00:25:025
2       00:11:21       00:41:32
3       00:34:39       00:58:01
```

So those are just a few lines of data, but there are close to 50 rows.

I'm really stuck on how to find overlapping time intervals. So that the difference between the "Start" of one row and the "End" of the next row has a value of at least one. I need it to compare each row to all other rows.

I was thinking it would involve a loop and some sort of conditional statement, but I'm having trouble debugging. My output will hopefully only include those rows that have overlap with other rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you were thinking of this as an N x N comparison, I would imagine that the answer would be some sort of ragged band matrix. (Look it up if band matrix is not a term you've seen before.) This code should test for overlap at the high end of the second column being greater than the first column, i.e., overlapping:

```
 Times <- read.table(text="
 Num     Start          End
 1       00:09:41       00:25:25
 2       00:11:21       00:41:32
 3       00:34:39       00:58:01", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)
 mdat <- outer(Times$Start, Times$End, function(x,y) y > x)
 mdat[upper.tri(mdat)|col(mdat)==row(mdat)] <- NA
 mdat
#------------------
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    NA   NA   NA
[2,]  TRUE   NA   NA
[3,] FALSE TRUE   NA
```

You are not interested in the diagonal since End is always greater than Start and the upper triangular portion of the test matrix is all going to be TRUE.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! That definitely works. Now I just need to figure out a way for it to display all of the "TRUE"s in a data frame - with columns "Num" "Start" and "End" Omitting those that don't overlap.