# Converting band matrix to frame and omitting certain rows?

Tags: r, dataframe

I received a lot of help previously, but I just ran into another issue, and was wondering if anyone would have any insight.

In a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666980/comparing-subsequent-rows-and-finding-overlapping-time-intervals), I wrote that I have a dataset (it actually has about 50 rows), let’s call it “Times”:

```
> Times <- read.csv(“Times.csv”, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)
> Times

Num     Start          End
1    00:09:41    00:25:025
2    00:11:21     00:41:32
3    00:34:39     00:58:01
```

Then, in order to find the overlapping time intervals, someone advised me to create a band matrix – comparing all of the rows.

```
Overlap <- outer (Times$Start, Times$End, function (x,y) y > x)
Overlap [upper.tri (Overlap) | col (Overlap) = = row(Overlap)] <- NA
Overlap

       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]           
[1,]     NA     NA     NA
[2,]   TRUE     NA     NA
[3,]  FALSE   TRUE     NA
```

So at this point, I know which rows overlap, but ideally I would like to have an output that resembles my original dataframe, but excluding those rows that don’t overlap any other rows.

Is there any way to omit rows that contain no TRUEs? And is it possible to convert this back to a dataframe?

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 1):

To exclude rows that don’t overlap any other rows.

```
Times[rowSums(is.na(Overlap)) < ncol(Overlap),]
```

**EDIT**

Since you are just interested in the lower part of Overlap matrix

```
 Overlap [upper.tri (Overlap) | col (Overlap) = = row(Overlap)] <- NA
```

You can skip this step and use lower part of the original Overlap to get this simple solution:

```
Overlap <- outer (Times$Start, Times$End, function (x,y) y > x)
Times[rowSums(lower.tri(mdat)) >0 ,]
```

Comment: +1 for rowSums (I guess .rowSums could also be used here), but I think you need to subset the Times df.

Comment: @SimonO101 yes of course. I need to subset Times. It was a typo.

Comment: Wow, that works great! Thanks for all the help. Hopefully one day I'll be able to help out newbies like me.

Answer (score 1):

How about....

```
exc <- apply( Overlap , 1 , function(x) all( is.na(x) ) )

nonoverlap <- Times[ ! exc , ]
```

Basically we look at each row of your `Overlap` matrix and return `TRUE` if all values are `NA`. We then use this to subset the `Times` dataframe, excluding those rows which were all `NA` in `Overlap`.